# Android Data Binding: missing DataBinderMapper class

Tags: android, data-binding

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.databinding.DataBinderMapper
        at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.<clinit>(DataBindingUtil.java:31)
        at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I hope this is a bug, does anyone face a similar problem? I unzipped `classes.jar` under the `exploded-arr` folder, but couldn't find the `DataBinderMapper` class.

Any workarounds / fixes would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a generated class so for some reason the annotation processor is not running. 
Can you share your gradle files ?

Comment: @yigit I have the same problem. Please help. [Here is my build.gradle](http://dropcanvas.com/0cmyz)

Comment: can u share a full project. Nothing obvious wrong in this build file

Answer (score 24):

#### Make sure that ALL your modules that use DataBinding have it enabled. This was the reason I got that exception.

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It really works. In my case, I only enable dataBinding for `feature-home` module but forgot to enable it in `app` module too. That's why I see this case. After adding dataBinding to `app` module too then it works as expected.

Comment: Lemme start a bounty and award this answer. tl;dr - if some `module` uses databinding, but application (`app`) module does not - it won't work anywhere. so `module` makes your `app` use it as well.

Comment: I had to enable databinding in `app` as well. This is the way.

Comment: A wise man once said that don't miss the comment section part If the answer is not working. @anticafe Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should include the android-apt plugin in your build.gradle in order to generate the `android.databinding.DataBinderMapper` class.

In your project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
//.... more
}
```

In each module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

[More information](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt)

Comment: android studio 2.3 no longer supports the android-apt plugin, any idea how this can be fixed now?

Comment: @shoe , get rid of android-apt plugin, that might help

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same error. What I have done is that I updated the dependency for **databinding** in **app.gradle** file

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0-alpha05'
```

to

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha04'
```

after updating the **databinder compiler**, I started getting this error. To get rid from this problem I have to revert the **databinding compiler** to old version and it taken me away from this problem. Now I am waiting for stable databinding compiler version and will upgrade to that version till then I will go with old compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue this last week, and was having a hard time figuring it out, but finally I discovered that I had two layouts with the same name in different libraries that each use databinding. I'm guessing this was causing the generated binding classes to end up in some kind of bad state at runtime.

I was able to troubleshoot it into a situation where, instead of getting this error on one Fragment, I got a `ClassCastException` to happen on the Fragment that had a layout with the same name. The generated Binding class was trying to cast a LinearLayout into a RelativeLayout. The only way it could be doing this is if it were trying to use a layout file from a completely different module that had the same name.

After making sure there were no layouts that share the same name -- even across different library modules -- it cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue when you run your tests, just add:

> ```
> kaptTest "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:+"
> ```

to `dependencies` on `build.gradle` files of all your modules.