# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.databinding.DataBinderMapperImpl when running Espresso tests

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-espresso

Data binding setup:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0"
}
```

The fragment class which uses data binding:

```
class LandingFragment : Fragment(), Injectable {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val dataBinding = LandingFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return dataBinding.root
    }
}
```

Every time the Espresso test is run for this fragment, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.databinding.DataBinderMapperImpl
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.<clinit>(DataBindingUtil.java:32)
at com.sc.databinding.LandingFragmentBinding.inflate(LandingFragmentBinding.java:42)
at com.sc.ui.landing.LandingFragment.onCreateView(LandingFragment.kt:32)
...
```

Comment: Is data binding enabled in your modules?

Comment: I have only one module "app".

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I don't remember how exactly, the issue disappeared by itself at some point.

Answer (score 27):

A bit late, but I resolved this issue by adding DataBinding compiler with kapt as a test dependency:

```
kaptAndroidTest 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.2'
```

Or the version not from AndroidX if your project is not using Jetpack yet.

Comment: I found this after one-hour searching. Made my day. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this necessary? What does it do? If this doesn't seem to fix it, try cleaning your build directory. I'm not sure why that works either.

Comment: Dude, do you use PayPal or something? :D

Comment: I hit this error when applying this solution, anyone has idea?
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction

Answer (score 2):

Add

> ```
> kaptTest "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:+"
> ```

to `dependencies` on `build.gradle` files of all your modules.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this very error. I did 2 things: 
1. Added kaptAndroidTest 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.5.1' in gradle 
2. Used the databinding, that is to say, I create a fake bool variable and injected it for real in a view. It would seem that you cannot just use databinding for retrieving the views instead of issuing the dreaded findViewById. You have to use it at least once in your module. Once you use it you are fine for all the other classes in your module.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

**I have the same this issue, and fixed by adding**

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

**in build.gradle app (all module if using dataBinding)**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"

}
```

**In build.gradle project**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.70'
    ext.android_plugin_version = '3.5.2'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add   **dataBinding = true**    to android { } in your build.gradle file, and everything will be fine, hope this help..

build.gradle:

```
android {

    // skip ..

    buildFeatures {
        //noinspection DataBindingWithoutKapt
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding true
    }


    // skip ..
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to add the android-apt plugin as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41098345/1852343) stackoverflow answer:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

Comment: I use kapt annotation processor (you can see it from my Gradle config). Why do I need the third party annotation processor?