# App crashes (Databinding Error) after AndroidX Migration

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding, androidx

I am trying to migrate a 3 yrs old project to AndroidX. The project have 3 modules.

- app
- sdk
- apis

**app** is the main module. The project builds AAR file of **sdk** and **apis** module on runtime. And the **app** uses **sdk** and **apis**

The changes I did in order to migrate are :

1. updated target version of app.gradle and gradlewrapper properties
2. migrated to AndroidX
3. updated all dependecies of all modules.

As the app starts, it launches an activity from **app** module which works fine. Just after that it launches an Activity from **sdk** module. But here the app crashes at DataBindingUtil.setContentView. Databinding is enabled for all 3 modules. Below is the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/databinding/library/baseAdapters/DataBinderMapperImpl;
    at com.xyz.sdk.DataBinderMapperImpl.collectDependencies(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:274)
    at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.addMapper(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:58)
    at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.addMapper(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:60)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapperImpl.<init>(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:5)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.<clinit>(DataBindingUtil.java:32)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
    at com.xyz.sdk.landing.LandingPageActivity.onCreate(LandingPageActivity.java:51)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters.DataBinderMapperImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.myapplication-fYwVmwZfRLEOIXuh0dvhUg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.admin.myapplication-fYwVmwZfRLEOIXuh0dvhUg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.xyz.sdk.DataBinderMapperImpl.collectDependencies(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:274) 
    at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.addMapper(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:58) 
    at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.addMapper(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:60) 
    at androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapperImpl.<init>(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:5) 
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.<clinit>(DataBindingUtil.java:32) 
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284) 
    at com.xyz.sdk.landing.LandingPageActivity.onCreate(LandingPageActivity.java:51) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40882253/6891563 does this help you?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same error. If you are working in a multi-module project, you need to enable `databinding` for the `app` modules that depend on libraries that use it.

So, my fix was to add this to the module using directly `databinding` and to my `app` module too.

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers. I have to add below lines in proguard.

```
-keep class androidx.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class * extends androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper { *; }
```