# Failed resolution of: Landroid/databinding/DataBindingUtil : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

module/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<package_id>"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true            
    }
    dataBinding {
            enabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
def gsonVersion = "2.6.2"
def gsonConverterVersion = "2.1.0"
def interceptorVersion = "3.3.0"
def supportVersion = "25.3.1"
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    //For Network Call
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$gsonConverterVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$interceptorVersion"

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
}
```

I have binded my activity with below code

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

It is showing me below error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/databinding/DataBindingUtil;
```

I have tried with [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882253/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-android-databinding-databindermapper) and [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554646/android-data-binding-missing-databindermapper-class) but it didn't work for me.

I have even tried with `clean and rebuild` and `invalidate Caches/Restart` but that also didn't help me.

Comment: Is your app working on above lollipop devices?

Comment: I am testing it with Nougat

Comment: I too started getting the error after I installed a new update on  9 september. I think there is some bug in the update coz my colleagues are having the same error after the update. Please post the solution if you get any.

Answer (score 1):

After trying without success:

- Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Sync project with gradle files
- Clean project
- Rebuild project
- `./gradlew clean`

I solved the issue as follow:

1. Deleting the folder `.idea/libraries`
2. File / Sync Project with Gradle Files
3. Build / Rebuild Project